# Clear single viewport in DirectX 10

Tags: directx, viewport, directx-10

I am preparing to start on a C++ DirectX 10 application that will consist of multiple "panels" to display different types of information.  I have had some success experimenting with multiple viewports on one RenderTargetView.  However, I cannot find a definitive answer regarding how to clear a single viewport at a time.  These panels (viewports) in my application will overlap in some areas, so I would like to be able to draw them from "bottom to top", clearing each viewport as I go so the drawing from lower panels doesn't show through on the higher ones.  In DirectX 9, it seems that there was a Clear() method of the device object that would clear only the currently set viewport.  DirectX 10 uses ClearRenderTargetView(), which clears the entire drawing area, and I cannot find any other option that is equivalent to the way DirectX 9 did it.

Is there a way in DirectX 10 to clear only a viewport/rectangle within the drawing area?  One person speculated that the only way may be to draw a quad in that space.  It seems that another possibility would be to have a seprate RenderTargetView for each panel, but I would like to avoid that as it requires other redundant resources, such as a separate depth/stencil buffers (unless that is a misunderstanding on my part).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using one render target per "viewport", and compositing them together using quads for the final view. I know of no way to scissor a clear in DX 10.

Also, according to the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "An array of render-target views may be passed into ID3D10Device::OMSetRenderTargets, however all of those render-target views will correspond to a single depth stencil view."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that is helpful.  I will do some more reading on using multiple render target views.  I guess I'm just a little confused about why, if render target views can be used to draw to different regions of a window, both render target views and viewports exist.

Comment: "All render targets must have the same size in all dimensions (width and height, and depth for 3D or array size for *Array types)."

Comment: That is from the same article you linked.  So I don't think this is what I want, as the panels of my user interface will vary in size.

Comment: I did think of that, is it possible you could make the rendertargets the largest possible size and then simply clip the rendering (viewport) and adjust the compositing quad's texture coordinates to match?

Comment: Heads up! My lack of DirectX knowledge is about to show through.  In the past I have always created a RenderTargetView (RTV) off of the back-buffer of my swap chain. If I understand what you're suggesting, I would create a separate texture resource for each RenderTargetView. I would use viewports to draw the the appropriate area (dimensions) of each RTV.  Then I would composite the RTVs to draw the final result to the back buffer. Is this right?  I have never done compositing of RTVs, and am not familiar with how I would transfer them to the back buffer. Know of any good samples online?

Comment: Thank you. I looked through the sample and it makes sense. I can see how this method would have it's benefits in some situations, but it seems like it may be more extra steps and overhead than it is worth for my needs. I think I may just use a single RenderTargetView with multiple viewports and just precede each viewport render with the drawing of a black quad in that viewport - with depth writes disabled so it doesn't affect further drawing of the scene. Still, your help and links have improved my understanding of these DirectX concepts, so thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just create a shader together with the appropriate blendstate settings and a square mesh (or other shape of mesh) and use it to clear the area where you want to clear? I haven't tried this but I think it can be done.